# Oracle Berkeley DB

Tags: openldap

I am trying to download the Oracle Berkeley DB , but I only see the 18.1 version and I would need 5.0 according to my OpenLDAP documentation.

https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/related/berkeleydb-downloads.html

When I go to "Previous releases" it takes me nowhere ( I tried with Firefox and Chrome )

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Kind regards.

Comment: Doesn't Openldap prefer LMDB ?

Comment: LMDB = MDB ? . If so, I have read that too. But I also read in the "INSTALL" document this : " ... This step ( make test ) requires the standalone LDAP server, slapd(8), with HDB and/or BDB support..."

Comment: Do you have a reference for that install document?  https://www.openldap.org/lists/openldap-announce/201907/msg00001.html

Comment: "H3: Database Software OpenLDAP's {{slapd}}(8) {{TERM:MDB}} primary database backend uses the {{TERM:LMDB}} software included with the OpenLDAP source.  There is no need to download any additional software to have {{MDB}} support." (https://git.openldap.org/openldap/openldap/-/blob/master/doc/guide/admin/install.sdf)

Comment: Gerard, I apologise but I didn't understand your question : "Do you have a reference for that install document?" . I meant to say the INSTALL document contained within the OpenLDAP package, once downloaded and unzipped.

Comment: OK, then where did you get this "package" that needs a "make test"?

Comment: From The Official OpenLDAP download site.

Comment: My guess is that you downloaded the source, instead of a package.  What distribution do you run?  The most recent release of openldap is available for almost all distributions.

Comment: Yes, the source. Sorry, I am new to OpenLDAP.

I run CentOS 7

; but somehow I don't feel my original question addressed. :)

Comment: I prefer giving people what they need, not what they ask for.

Comment: I see. Thanks once again Gerard.

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on building openldap yourself, Debian has a copy of the sources for libdb5.3: [db5.3](http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/d/db5.3/db5.3_5.3.28-9+deb8u1.debian.tar.xz)

Comment: Thanks Gerald. I have to build it from the sources , but not Debian. I am dealing with CentOS.

Comment: The source is the source.  It has no relation to a distribution.  This is the one from the most recent CentOS 7: https://archive.kernel.org/centos-vault/7.8.2003/os/Source/SPackages/libdb-5.3.21-25.el7.src.rpm